# How to insert a data into RDB (MySQL) using Spark?

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to insert a data into `MySQL` table via `Spark SQL`.

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE images (
  id    INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  data  LONGBLOB     NOT NULL
);
```

and my `Spark` code:

```
case class Image(name: String, data: Array[Byte])

def saveImage(image: Image): Unit = {
  sqlContext.sql(s"""INSERT INTO images (name, data) VALUES ('${image.name}', ${image.data});""".stripMargin)
}
```

But I get an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.13] failure: ``table'' expected but identifier images found
INSERT INTO images (name, data)
            ^
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: try add ` to your column name. \`images\`

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I've found a solution. I can use a trick to save data into MySQL using Spark SQL. The trick is to create a new DataFrame and then to persist it. Here is an example:

```
def saveImage(image: Image): Unit = {
  val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame {
    sc.parallelize(
      Image(
        name = image.name,
        data = image.data
      ) :: Nil
    )
  }

  JdbcUtils.saveTable(df, url, "images", props)      
}
```

And the model would be like this:

```
case class Image(
  id   : Option[Int] = None,
  name : String,
  data : Array[Byte]
)
```